# Ensure a file is written to a computer prior to executing commands

Tags: python, python-3.x, ssh, sftp, file-transfer

I am using Python 3.8's SFTP with SSH Client to write a file to a remote computer on a remote connection. However, I want to ensure that the file is written to the computer prior to executing further commands on the system. Is there a way I can ensure this? This is an API function performed on a POST request. What if I want to remove a file and rewrite the contents. (In this case, I do a delete and a write, but is there a more efficient way to do this?) Template Code is Below.

```
 def APICall(SSH_client, event):
     fileContent = event['body']['content']
     if event['body']['rewrite'] == 'true':
           SSH_client.exec_command('rm fileName')
     ftp = SSH_client.open_sftp()
     file = ftp.file("fileName","a",-1)
     file.write(fileContent)
     file.flush()
     ftp.close()
     commands = [commands]
     for command in commands:
           SSH_client.exec_command(command)
```

If anything is unclear in my question, please do ask for further context.

Comment: If `flush()` succeeds, the remote system is claiming that the file is written, at least as far as the VFS layer -- where it's visible to other process (not specified whether it's actually persisted to be able to survive disk). Do you have reason to believe that the remote server is lying to you?

Comment: BTW, `exec_command` is a lot of overhead -- if you have a SFTP connection, better to use that for your delete; it's a lot more efficient to just directly -- via the sftp subsystem you're already using -- invoke the `unlink()` syscall than to start a shell that in turn starts `/bin/rm` and then has _that_ program call `unlink()`.

Comment: That said, the _safer_ way to rewrite any file is to create a completely new temporary file with a unique, random name; write it; and then rename that temporary name to the "real" name. (That's not specific to sftp, it's the best-practice on UNIX systems in general: Do it that way, and even if your program is interrupted, there'll always be a complete copy of the file in place, whether it's the old one or the new one).

Comment: Is there a way to wait on the flush command until it succeeds?

Comment: It's a synchronous call. When you get control back, it has succeeded.

Comment: If I need to run commands based on the newest version of the file, is there an optimal way to handle this?

Comment: As I said earlier -- create-and-rename is the accepted best practice. It's how _every_ major well-designed package management tool works. You use `apt` or `rpm` to upgrade a package? They're creating each file under a new name, writing it in full, closing/flushing, and then renaming to the final name.

Comment: Sounds good, I will implement this in my API

Comment: Should I use `mv` or `cp -f`

Comment: `cp` is not a rename at all. It needs to be `mv` if you're using either of those two, but `sftp` gives you a more direct call for that: http://docs.paramiko.org/en/stable/api/sftp.html#paramiko.sftp_client.SFTPClient.posix_rename